# How can I prevent IF statement from running once the condition is met

Tags: javascript, if-statement, event-handling, dom-events

I'm making a game where players have to input numbers to guess the population of a country, but I'm having issues counting their scores. I have this if statement:

```
 if (player1 === "" || player2 === "") {
          resultSpan.innerHTML = "One or two empty values";
        } else {
          resultSpan.innerHTML = `The correct number is ${population.toLocaleString()}`;
          let playerWin = document.querySelector(".results-player-win");

          if (
            Math.abs(parseInt(population) - playerOneTotal) <
            Math.abs(parseInt(population) - playerTwoTotal)
          ) {
            playerWin.innerText = "Player 1 wins!";
            playerOneScore++;
          }

          if (
            Math.abs(parseInt(population) - playerOneTotal) >
            Math.abs(parseInt(population) - playerTwoTotal)
          ) {
            playerWin.innerText = "Player 2 wins!";
            playerTwoScore++;
          }
          document.getElementById(
            "current-score"
          ).innerHTML = `P1: ${playerOneScore} --- P2: ${playerTwoScore}`;
        }
```

But, instead of incrementing the score by 1, sometimes it's two or three. I'm guessing this is because another `eventListener` is being called beforehand. However, I can't find a way to separate them completely, as they both need to use the same population variable for the score to be calculated correctly.

I've tried adding `this.remove()` inside of the IF statements, but it deletes the button. I've also tried `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` and creating a variable `isFirst`, and setting to true then false, but they block the code completely on second execution.

For more clarity, I'm also posting a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ub65zxfe/5/#).

Comment: You might want to add `.trim()` to the input values of the first if statement: `if (player1.trim() === "" || player2.trim() === "")`

Comment: Also, it will help to make the example [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but doesn't help solve my issue? The code definitely needs to be reformatted, but for now I'm just trying to get it to work as expected. Also, this is my first time posting a question, sorry if something's unclear.

Comment: That's why I added it as an answer. If I was trying to answer your question, I would have added an answer. I just made that comment to help you with parts of your code that aren't part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by initializing the variables

```
playerOneScore = 0;
playerTwoScore = 0
```

; (the ones that track the score) in the global environment. I also added `{ once: true }` to the listener that tracks user input/scores as clicking the button multiple times would cause unwanted behaviour.